# Use Index Match to pull multiple columns of data

Tags: excel, vba

The following script allows users to perform an Index Match function through a series of Input Boxes. This version only allows users to pull one column of data per use. I'm wondering if its possible to change this code to allow users to pull multiple columns of data. I appreciate any feedback the community can provide.

```
Sub MatchMaster()

'this script helps simplify the use of Excel's Index Match function
'place this script in your personal macro workbook and assign it to a button
'use it to pull data between two worksheets that share unique identifiers

'dim ranges
Dim ValuesToPull As Range
Dim TargetIDs As Range
Dim SourceIDs As Range
Dim MyRange As Range

'dim worksheets
Dim Source1 As Worksheet
Dim Target1 As Worksheet
Dim Source2 As Worksheet
Dim Target2 As Worksheet

'input box dims
Dim Prompt1 As String
Dim Prompt2 As String
Dim Prompt3 As String
Dim Prompt4 As String
Dim Title1 As String
Dim Title2 As String
Dim Title3 As String
Dim Title4 As String

'set prompts
Prompt1 = "Select values to pull (1 column only)"
Prompt2 = "Select unique IDs on target sheet (1 column only)"
Prompt3 = "Select unique IDs on source sheet (1 column only)"
Prompt4 = "Where should we put these values? (1 column only)"

'set titles
Title1 = "Source Sheet"
Title2 = "Target Sheet"
Title3 = "Source Sheet"
Title4 = "Target Sheet"

'error handling
On Error GoTo OuttaHere

'input boxes
Set SourceIDs = Application.InputBox(Prompt3, Title3, Type:=8)
Set Source1 = SourceIDs.Worksheet
SourceIDcolumn = SourceIDs.Column
LastSourceID = Source1.Cells(Rows.Count, SourceIDcolumn).End(xlUp).Row
Source1.Activate

Set ValuesToPull = Application.InputBox(Prompt1, Title1, Type:=8)
Set Source2 = ValuesToPull.Worksheet
ValuesColumn = ValuesToPull.Column
LastValue = Source2.Cells(Rows.Count, ValuesColumn).End(xlUp).Row
Source2.Activate

Set TargetIDs = Application.InputBox(Prompt2, Title2, Type:=8)
Set Target1 = TargetIDs.Worksheet
TargetIDcolumn = TargetIDs.Column
LastTargetID = Target1.Cells(Rows.Count, TargetIDcolumn).End(xlUp).Row '<~~ also use this for MyRange
Target1.Activate

Set MyRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt4, Title4, Type:=8)
Set Target2 = MyRange.Worksheet
MyColumn = MyRange.Column
Target2.Activate

'convert input to Range Cells format
With Source1
    Set SourceIDs = .Range(.Cells(1, SourceIDcolumn), .Cells(LastSourceID, SourceIDcolumn))
End With

With Source2
    Set ValuesToPull = .Range(.Cells(1, ValuesColumn), .Cells(LastValue, ValuesColumn))
End With

With Target1
     Set TargetIDs = .Range(.Cells(1, TargetIDcolumn), .Cells(LastTargetID, TargetIDcolumn))
End With

With Target2
     Set MyRange = .Range(.Cells(1, MyColumn), .Cells(LastTargetID, MyColumn))
End With

'apply formula
MyRange = Application.Index(ValuesToPull, Application.Match(TargetIDs, SourceIDs, 0))

OuttaHere:
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: Not to be facetious... but wouldn't it be easier to just teach them how to use INDEX-MATCH?

Comment: I'd actually like to figure this out for myself as well. I find manually entering multiple Index Match formulas rather tedious

Comment: get the proper row from the match alone. then use something like this `.Range("A:D").Rows(i).Values` where i is the number returned by the match.  It will return an array of four values at that row.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks Scott, this sounds interesting. Any chance you have a working example of this being utilized?

Comment: I just gave you one, here is another ActiveSheet.Range("A5:N100").Rows(3).Address` which will return the address `$A$7:$N$7`  Just use your match alone and allow the user to select multiple columns and set that as the range and match as the row.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks Scott, let me see what I can do.